# Is there a more efficient way to parse information in lxml

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, lxml

Recently I started making a YouTube video information extractor using BeautifulSoup and benchmarked it to realise it was quite slow (somewhere around 1-3 seconds per video) and would be inefficient when it had to query large lists of url's

After looking at some benchmarks of a parser named lxml(claimed to be 30x faster), I decided to change my project's HTML parser to lxml and surprisingly the performance did quite increase (by 30%)

The performance increase is a good sign but still not enough for large datasets, I doubt it has something to do with my parsing approach

Anyways, here is my current approach to fetch the various information from a youtube video

```
#advadata is html document loaded in lxml

self.views=advdata.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'watch-view-count')]")[0].text
self.published_on=advdata.xpath("//strong[contains(@class,'watch-time-text')]")[0].text 
self.channel="https://youtube.com"+advdata.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'yt-user-info')]/a/@href")[0]
self.creator=advdata.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'yt-user-info')]/a")[0].text
self.likes=advdata.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'like-button-renderer-like-button')]/span")[0].text#like-button-renderer-like-button
self.dislikes=advdata.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'like-button-renderer-dislike-button')]/span")[0].text#like-button-renderer-dislike-button
self.description=advdata.xpath("//p[contains(@id,'eow-description')]")[0].text#eow-description
```

Now my question is whether I am parsing the information the right way and if I'm not, is there a faster way to parse data?

Comment: You could try not search globally > extend the xpath to be as close as possible to the tag you need. There is a [benchmark](https://pugixml.org/benchmark.html) not sure if it is reliable, but there are other XML libraries listed claimed to be faster than lxml/libxml2. Some of that are available for Python ... but i never benchmarked them myself.

Comment: Thanks for the benchmarks, I guess you are right as it looks like locating different elements globally does take up a lot of cpu usage hence increasing the overall time. I might need to change my approach a little bit to get the performance I need. Thanks for the solution again

Comment: Are you sure these xpaths are the issue? Have you profiled your entire program to see what the bottlenecks are? (PyCharm professional version has a good profiler and a trial version. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/profiler.html)

Comment: @Daniel Haley i redid the benchmarks, i realised that the way i benchmarked it before was wrong and it actually took 15ms to parse and locate all the information I wanted to extract. The benchmarks i did accidentally included the time it took for the request to complete which was about 900ms. No wonder it took over 2-3s for it complete